# Hostel scanned my credit card

Tags: usa, payment-cards, hostels

I just arrived in New York and the woman at the reception scanned my passport (ok, happens everywhere) AND my credit card!
The thing about my credit card: it has the credit card number and the CCV on the same side.

Is that legally even allowed? I've been traveling the world for 9 month and no hostel ever scanned my credit card.

She said they need it as a deposit (otherwise 50$) and will delete it after I check out. Just sounds like some blabla. It feels very unsafe to me.

Comment: Allowed? Sure. But it's also why I insist on paying deposits in cash. You can demand they delete the scan and give them the cash, but there's no guarantee there's not a backup somewhere.

Comment: Well she didn't ask. She asked for my passport and credit card, which is also normal, to verify the payment. Then she just started scanning both.

Comment: What's done is done. Personally I would ask that they delete the scan, give her the cash deposit, and request a new card from my bank/credit card company and that the old one be cancelled.

Comment: They might say they "deleted" it, but in reality didn't. But I agree with @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, what's done has been done. If you really feel worried, watch your account to see if anything suspicious comes up.

Comment: Ya, luckily I'm at the end of traveling and won't use the card that much at home. So It's easy to spot any fraud attempts.

Comment: Having the CCV and number on the same side would be enough reason for me to cancel the card and get a new one.

Comment: @greenstonewalkar - AMEX cards all have the ccv on the front.

Comment: I don't understand the consternation. This would be the expected behavior at a hotel, even when you have pre-paid for the accommodation, to cover incidentals or damage. Same with a rental car.

Comment: When you get home, phone your credit card company and say you are worried about identity theft and request a new number and new card.

Comment: Lets be realistic, if the people working at the hotel are criminal, they are going to get your card details no matter how they "process" it.  Many hotels still do a manual imprint of your card, others make a photocopy. The only cure to identity theft paranoia is using cash.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas It is not. They can get a pre-authorization for your credit card. No need to make a scan.

Comment: @Tom No criminal intent from the hotel required. Just sloppy handling of the paper scans, or someone breaching their server with the electronic scans.

Comment: @JanDoggen - sorry, but I don't know what your reply is in reference to. My point is that there's a difference between a hotel taking a payment, and them keeping a scan/photocopy of both the card number and pin in a potentially unsecure location. I've gotten equally discomfited when discovering that my hostel keeps the copy of my passport they took at registration in an unlocked drawer in the front desk where anyone could get at it.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Sorry, misdirected, meant to refer to choster's comment *This would be the expected behavior at a hotel*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The thing about my credit card: it has the credit card number and the CCV on the same side.
>
> Is that legally even allowed?

Storing the CVV field after authorization (in any format, encrypted or not) is not permitted under The Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard.

> Sensitive authentication data must never be stored after authorization – even if this data is encrypted.
> [...]
> • Never store the card-validation code or value (three- or four-digit number printed on the front or back of a payment card used to validate card-not-present transactions).

See this [fact sheet](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf).

Additionally, scanning the card seems to me to raise other concerns about the physical security of the computers on which the images are stored, and the technical security in effect on that computer, and the vetting and training of staff who are authorized to access the computer; but it is perhaps possible the merchant is complaint with the PCI-DSS in this respect.

A merchant who violates the PCI-DSS may be fined by the acquirer or lose their access to the card network, depending on their merchant agreement.

In some places and in some US states, compliance with the PCI-DSS is legally required. But I do not think it is required in New York. Other local law may impose similar provisions to the PCI-DSS though.

---

In your shoes, I would complain to my credit card issuer, on the basis that the issuer is doing business with an unreputable merchant and I was disappointed that the high reputation of the card network has been tarnished by its association with this merchant.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the time, hotels take a card and swipe/scan it for incidentals such as the minibar, room service, laundry etc. however I haven't had this happen to me at a hostel before. I'm sure it's just the same kind of situation and the hostel is more of a higher end version of what I have experienced before. I wouldn't worry, but if you are, just keep an eye on your statements and report anything suspicious to your bank. With the security number on the front it sounds like an Amex to me, and they are extremely stringent with fraudulent activity.